# How to play a custom sound when user gets a notification from my program

Tags: vb.net, windows, notifications

I've created an application using vb .net that indicates caps lock and num lock status. The application sends **Baloon** notifications whenever the lock state changes. You may know that the system plays a default notification sound when a notification is sent from an application. I want to change the sound for my application. I mean is there any code I can use in my application that enables the application to play a custom sound (from a .wav file) instead of the default sound during the notification?

**EDIT:**
Here's the code:

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown


If Key = Keys.CapsLock Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock = False Then
                ButtonToggleCaps.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustButton2

            NotifyIconCaps.Icon = My.Resources.TrayIcon_Lime_Caps_Off
            NotifyIconCaps.ShowBalloonTip(500)
            NotifyIconCaps.BalloonTipText = "Caps Lock OFF"
            ShowInTaskbar = False

        ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock = True Then
            ButtonToggleCaps.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustButton1

            NotifyIconCaps.Icon = My.Resources.TrayIcon_Lime_Caps_On
            NotifyIconCaps.ShowBalloonTip(500)
            NotifyIconCaps.BalloonTipText = "Caps Lock ON"
            ShowInTaskbar = False
            End If
        End If
        End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
If it is not possible to change the default notification sound, can we at least disable the default sound so that my application can play a custom sound whenever the notification is displayed?

Comment: What do you mean by "application sends system notifications".  Do you mean a balloon or toast popup?  What exact API are you calling?  (e.g. show your code)

Comment: @selbie I mean a baloon notification